# Logo/ icon cant work properly

Tags: android

I make a webview app through android studio and upload it playstore. Now when I try to install it on Redmi 5/ redmi y1 my logo does not appear but on other mobiles show the logo. On redmi 5/ y1 its show only Default icon. How to solve it?

Comment: Move it to `res/drawable`?

Comment: Yes.. I done all things.

Comment: This problem is only come with some device..

Comment: are you using updated version of chrome in mobile app

Comment: Why I update Chrome? I make my own app.

Comment: If you moved it to the regular Drawable (or mipmap) folder, then it should be loaded by all devices since there is no qualifier. And if you get the default otherwise, remove any other matching files from the qualified folders https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html